# How many dimensions Big Bang had?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion, big-bang, spacetime-dimensions

I just watched "Through the Wormhole S01E04 What Happened Before the Beginning" and a question just popped into my head.
Time dimension should not exist at that moment I think, but I wonder at the exact moment of the Big Bang how many dimensions were there or how many dimensions had Big Bang?

Comment: What detail should I add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Big Bang is generally modelled by GR and was in fact a prediction of GR. However, at the time of the Big Bang there is a singularity and so GR is no help there.

It's thought that a theory of quantum gravity may help with resolving the problematic singularity, but there is no widely accepted theory of quantum gravity.

However, one leading contender for a theory of quantum gravity is srring theory. Here, one prominant string theorist has suggested that the dimension of spacetime might be a dynamical parameter, in the same way that spacetime becamecdynamical in GR. But given that heterotic string theories have differing dimensions of right and left movers it might be best to think that these so-called extra spacetime dimensions has nothing to do with spacetime as generally understood.

Comment: By "one prominant string theorist" do you mean professor Leonard Susskind's work?

Comment: I do not understand the protocol for the present handling for the OP question. The question itself is clear enough in spite of the confusion of the asker regarding the science. The answer by user292096 seems very clear, but not quite complete. I think the questioner would be helped by a discussion of the Planck Epoch allowing speculations for (1) an infinite past, as well as (2) a smooth t=o beginning rather than a singularity.

Comment: @R1W: I don't recall. If you want to check, it's in the latter third of Rickles *A Brief History of String Theory*.

Answer (score 3):

In classical general relativity, a singularity is not a point or a point set. Its dimensionality is not well defined.